# clang complains about constexpr function in case for switch statement

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct X
    {
    enum class E
    {
        A,B
    };

    static constexpr X A()
    {
        return X{E::A};
    }

    static constexpr X B()
    {
        return X{E::B};
    }

    constexpr operator E() const
    {
        return a;
    }
    E a;
};

template <typename T>
struct Y
{
    void f()
    {
        // without this line clang errs
        // const auto & x = this->x;
        switch(x)
        {
            case X::A():
            case X::B():
            default: return;
        }
    }

    X x = X::A();
};

int main()
{
    Y<int>{}.f();
}
```

Without the marked line in the snippet clang gives the following error:

> error: case value is not a constant expression case
>
> X::B():

However I tried gcc and it compiled fine. Anybody knows if gcc is being lenient or clang has some bug?

See on godbolt (clang 8.0.0): https://godbolt.org/z/ETe5WQ
However (gcc 8.3) compiles fine (also on godbolt) and tried other versions of gcc and were also fine

Update:

opened a [bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41241)

Comment: @mkmostafa if you suspect compiler error it would not hurt to specify compiler versions you were using both gcc and clang.

Comment: It compiles if you change switch(x) to switch(this->x)

Comment: Also compiles with clang 5 and clang 6: https://godbolt.org/z/KHMnoX I suggest filing a bug at https://bugs.llvm.org/

Answer (score 14):

**Clang (8.0.0) has a bug here.**

If you write `constexpr auto A = X::A();` and use `case A:` in your `switch` statement, you get the same compile error (saying that `A` *is not* a constant expression).

If you remove the cases, however, it compiles fine (which implies that `A` *is* a valid `constexpr` => a contradiction to the previous error).

Moreover, `switch(x)` fails while `switch(this->x)` succeeds. Since [`x == this->x`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.mfct.non-static#3) in your case, this is definitely a bug.

As chtz mentioned, clang (5/6) seem to work just fine. That's not an argument, but an apparent regression.

*Update:* As mentioned by the OP, they filed a [bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41241).

Comment: This bug also affects Clang versions 7.0.0 through 9.0.1 and appears to be fixed in 10.0.0. At least that's what I got when pasting the code from the bug report into godbolt.

Answer (score 2):

It appears clang doesn't work out that `switch(x)` is a switch on the enum `X::E`.

If you add an explicit cast to `X::E` (`static_cast` or C-style or whatever) your code compiles without your change.

This only happens when your class is a `template`.

Using `switch(this->x)` also works.

As whenever `x` is a member of the class, `x` is just another name for `this->x` even in a `template`, this has to be a clang bug.

The rules for how you can do a switch on a non-enum/integral type are interesting, in that they rely on the existence of an unspecified casting operator to any enum or integral type in the `switch` expression, and then invoke the same cast in the `case` expression.